# Woocommerce Subtotal Only Numbers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to get the float value from WooCommerce's cart

don't want to parse this function:
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();

is there any way to get clean subtotal from the woocommerce's cart?

it suppose to be really simple, but i'm stuck :)

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the cart class's `get_cart_subtotal()` method, I believe you could do something like:

```
if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {

    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;

} else {

    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

}
```

This assumes that you *aren't* doing compounded tax. The unformatted subtotals seem to be stored as class variables.